# While loop going past limit

Tags: c++

```
while (('\0' != *str1) && ('\0' != *str2) &&
    (false == sensi) ? (std::toupper(*str1) == std::toupper(*str2)) : (*str1 == *str2)) {
    ++str1;
    ++str2;
}
```

This code keeps looping even past the NULL terminator.

There must be something incredibly obvious I am missing here, but I simply cannot see it.

If either one of those chunks of code between the `&&` gets evaluated as false, it should break, but it does not do so and keeps parsing the string even past the NULL terminator into gibberish.

Comment: Show the full code and example input, demonstrating that the strings are null-terminated, etc. Also - note that the `?:` operator has lower precedence than nearly everything, so if you meant it to be the 3rd and condition, it's not acting like that right now; instead, you are testing the 3 conditions as input to the ternary, and using its output as the only `while` test. You probably want to wrap the entire ternary clause in parentheses (and maybe drop some of the other, redundant ones).

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `false == sensi` is usually written `!sensi`. Or skip the negation: `sensi ? *str1 == *str2 : std::toupper(*str1) == std::toupper(*str2)`.

Comment: Well, that may be true, but I assume the compiler will do the exact same thing to it anyways when optimizing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cpp
while (('\0' != *str1) && ('\0' != *str2) &&
    (false == sensi) ? (std::toupper(*str1) == std::toupper(*str2)) : (*str1 == *str2))
```

The ternary operator `?:` has lower precedence than nearly all other operators, including the logical AND `&&`. So, the `&&`s get applied first, and thus what you are saying here is:

- if `str1` is not at its `NUL` terminator, `&&` `str2` is not at its own, `&&` we are not comparing case-sensitively,
- then `?` loop `while` the strings' current characters are equal case-insensitively,
- else `:` loop `while` the strings' current characters are equal exactly.

Therefore, you will loop forever if the strings are equal, or at least past their `NUL` terminators and into Undefined Behaviour Land.

---

What you instead mean is this, where we wrap the entire ternary expression in parentheses, to override its default precedence and thus make the language evaluate it as the 3rd condition of the `&&`:

```cpp
while ( *str1 != '\0' && *str2 != '\0' &&
        (!sensi ? std::toupper(*str1) == std::toupper(*str2) : *str1 == *str2) )
```

i.e. to loop `while`:

- `str1` is not at its `NUL` terminator, `&&`
- `str2` is not at its own, `&&`
- `(` the strings' current characters are equal in `?:` the way specified by `sensi` `)`.

---

I would suggest to review operator precedence [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), not overuse parentheses where redundant, and not use Yoda conditionals. Also, this large compound condition could perhaps best be expressed as a separate function taking the 2 `str`s as input and checking each condition separately, to avoid confusing long logical tests.

Comment: It seems you are right, I messed up the paranthesis due to not knowing what operator precendence was. Thanks a lot, bro